# SIM300 send sms in Mikroc using PIC16f

Tags: sms, gsm, pic, mikroc

I have been trying to send SMS using an SIM300 module. Though module is working fine when tried using Hyper Terminal, but i am not able to send the SMS using PIC.

Below is the code that i tried (LCD also included (Lcd is working fine)):

> Programming: MikroC
>   Controller : PIC16f877A
>   Module: SIM300

```
sbit LCD_RS at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;

// Pin direction

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;

void main(){
//CMCON = 7;                        //Disable Comparators
Lcd_Init();                        // Initialize LCD
UART1_init(9600);                   //Initiate baud rate to 9600
Delay_ms(500);                      //Delay
UART1_Write_Text("AT+CMGF=1");      //Write "AT+CMGF=1"
UART1_Write(0x0D);                  // mean (ENTER)
Delay_ms(500);                      //Delay
UART1_Write_Text("AT+CMGS=");       //Write "AT+CMGS="
UART1_Write(0x22);                  //Write (")
UART1_Write_Text("9449869619");     //Number SMS send to
UART1_Write(0x22);                  //Write (")
UART1_Write(0x0D);                  // mean (ENTER)
Delay_ms(500);                      //Delay
UART1_Write_Text("WELCOME");
UART1_Write(0x0D);      //Words to be sent
UART1_Write(0x1A);
                //Write "ctrl+z"
Delay_ms(500);                      //Delay
Lcd_Out(1,1,"MSG SENT SUCESSFULLY"); // Write text in first row

}
```

Comment: You tested the module with Hyperterminal? Did you try testing your PIC with Hyperterminal?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

Uart1_Write_Text("AT+CMGF=1\r");

because the "\r" represents "enter" or "return" and sometimes "0x0D" doesn't work in microcontrollers.

I've been using it and it works fine for me.